# How to track file deletion or renaming for files of a particular extension?

Tags: windows-xp, security

I do not want to restrict deletion, as it may be required in some genuine cases. However, I need to track accidental or intentional deletion or renaming of files of a particular extension, has been done by which user and at what time.

Also I need to track the user names and date times when particular folders have been modified. Windows shows the last modified time, but I need to track the history of modifications.

Operating System is Windows XP and File System is NTFS.

Comment: I went through this link: http://sogeeky.blogspot.in/2006/07/how-to-audit-and-track-file-deletions.html. It gives partial solution, like specific folders can be tracked. I tried to implement it. Even for file rename operation, it generates a Delete event log, which is fine. However, it will be helpful to know what is the renamed file name.

Comment: Process Monitor, from sysinternals.com, can probably help. I know you can set up a series of filters for it, but it does have an overhead.

Comment: Process Monitor is probably a real time monitor. I need to track file and folder deletion and renaming operations for last 60 days. Windows Local Account Policy looks to be fine, but it does not capture the renamed file's new name.

Comment: Also I want the logging to be done silently, without the user being aware of it.